# Find the exact matched string from the variable

Tags: powershell

In the below code, `$Result` variable has the following information. I need to iterate below each line in `$Result` variable and get the `<APPPOOL NAME>` that is, "DefaultAppPool","Classic .NET AppPool" & ".NET v2.0 Classic" as an input to the second `Invoke-Command` saved in `$Result2`. Please advise how this can be accomplished.

`$Result` output:

```
APPPOOL "DefaultAppPool" (MgdVersion:v4.0,MgdMode:Integrated,state:Started)  
APPPOOL "Classic .NET AppPool" (MgdVersion:v2.0,MgdMode:Classic,state:Started)
APPPOOL ".NET v2.0 Classic" (MgdVersion:v2.0,MgdMode:Classic,state:Started)
```

---

```
$Username = '<username>'
$Password = '<Password>'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $pass 

$input_file_path = "servers.txt"
$output_path = "result.txt"

foreach ($server in Get-Content $input_file_path) {
    $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
        C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list apppools
    }
    $Result | Add-Content $output_path
    $Result2 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName #server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
        C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list apppools <APPPOOL NAME> /text:processmodel.username
    }
}
```

Comment: `$APPPOOL = ($Result -split '"')[1]`

Comment: You can also call native cmdlets (`WebAdministration`) for IIS information: `Import-Module -Name WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools`